# Count the amount of times a word appears in BigQuery column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with some long strings and need to count the most used words in it.

I need something that works like this https://towardsdatascience.com/very-simple-python-script-for-extracting-most-common-words-from-a-story-1e3570d0b9d0. The word counting part at least...

And it is very important that i have the option to blacklist some words so they dont count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below simple approach

```
with blacklist as (
  select 'with' word union all 
  select 'that' union all
  select 'add more as you see needed'
)
select lower(word) word, count(*) frequency
from data, unnest(regexp_extract_all(col, r'[\w]*')) word
where length(word) > 3  
and word not in (select word from blacklist)
group by word
order by frequency desc
```

Comment: it didnt work... the phrases are in portuguese, could this be the problem? or maybe i didnt make the right substituion on your code idk

Comment: ),
blacklist as (
  select 'with' word union all 
  select 'that' union all
  select 'add more as you see needed'
)
select lower(word) word, count(*) frequency
from T0, unnest(regexp_extract_all(T0.column, r'[\w]*')) word
where length(word) > 3  
and word not in (select word from blacklist)
group by word
order by frequency desc

///i tried this..

Comment: please be more specific - what you mean by "it didnt work"? provide example of input data. etc....

Comment: my bad, i receive this message "This query returned no results".

Comment: never mind, i had a mistake on my original query, it works perfectly now, thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Glad it works for you. Consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Comment: btw, im looking at the results and the code is cutting words that contain some "brazilian letters" like "Ç" "ã" "õ", is there a way to make it consider those.
In a word like "informação", it counts as "informa"

Comment: sure doable, will check shortly. but meantime check my in my other answers how to treat accents, etc. It should be at least few answers related to that :o)

Comment: i found it on google hehe, i changed r'[\w]*' for r'[A-zà-ú0-9]*'. And it worked, and again thank you so much

Comment: exactly! great job :o)